# How to get most common for each element of array list (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a List of arrays for which I need to find highest frequency element for each element of the list.For following code "unhashable type: 'list'" error is thrown.However I have also tried to parallelize the results list but the error remains.

```py
# [array(0,1,1),array(0,0,1),array(1,1,0)] example of list
  
    
def finalml(listn):
    return Counter(listn).most_common(1)


# the array list is return by this 
results = sn.rdd.map(lambda xw: bc_knnobj.value.kneighbors(xw, return_distance=False)).collect() 
        
labels = results.map(lambda xw: finalml(xw)).collect()
```

##### Expected Output

```
[1,0,1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try maybe this:

```
x = [[0,1,1],[0,0,1],[1,1,0]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(x)
df.show()
```

Input df:

```
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  1|
|  0|  0|  1|
|  1|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
@F.udf
def mode(x):
    from collections import Counter
    return Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0]

cols = df.columns
agg_expr = [mode(F.collect_list(col)).alias(col) for col in cols]
df.groupBy().agg(*agg_expr).show()
```

Output df:

```
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+
```