# In Pyspark get most frequent string from a column with list of strings

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Working with a dataframe which contains a column, the values in the columns are lists,

```
id    |   values
1     |   ['good','good','good','bad','bad','good','good']
2     |   ['bad','badd','good','bad',Null,'good','bad']
....
```

How could I get the most frequent showed string in the list?
expected output:

```
id   | most_frequent
1    | 'good'
2    | 'bad'
....
```

Comment: did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460067/how-to-get-most-common-for-each-element-of-array-list-pyspark) ?

Comment: This is for the whole column, I need to find max for each list in the values column.

Comment: Yes, well the same udf could be used for a single column of arrays too. However, for spark 2.4+ , the accepted answer is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont see a reason to **`explode`** and **`groupby`** here (compute intensive shuffle operations), as with **`Spark2.4+`**, we can use **`higher order functions`** to get your desired output:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df\
  .withColumn("most_common", F.expr("""sort_array(transform(array_distinct(values),\
                                      x-> array(aggregate(values, 0,(acc,t)->acc+IF(t=x,1,0)),x)),False)[0][1]"""))\
  .show(truncate=False)

#+---+----------------------------------------+-----------+
#|id |values                                  |most_common|
#+---+----------------------------------------+-----------+
#|1  |[good, good, good, bad, bad, good, good]|good       |
#|2  |[bad, badd, good, bad,, good, bad]      |bad        |
#+---+----------------------------------------+-----------+
```

We can also use **`array_max`** instead of **`sort_array`**.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df\
  .withColumn("most_common", F.expr("""array_max(transform(array_distinct(values),\
                                      x-> array(aggregate(values, 0,(acc,t)->acc+IF(t=x,1,0)),x)))[1]"""))\
  .show(truncate=False)
```